# Can UITextFields defined in a view controller's xib be used in UITableViewCells?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to do something that I'd think would be fairly straightforward and perfectly acceptable to do. Except, it seems to be neither.

I've created a XIB whose owner is a view controller. In that XIB I've created, among other things, multiple UITextFields, and wired them to appropriate IBOutlets in the view controller. The view controller is also the delegate for a UITableView which is contained within the controller's main view.

In *tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:* I then create a UITableViewCell as you'd expect me to (reuse identifiers, etc). I then add the appropriate IBOutletted UITextField (depending on the current row) to the UITableViewCell's contentView (after first invoking removeFromSuperview on the UITextField).

This works fine when the view initially loads. However, once I start performing actions that cause the UITableView to reload its data, weird things happen with the UITextFields. Namely, most of them start disappearing from the tableview, while others shrink dramatically in width.

So, am I doing something I shouldn't be doing? As you can guess, configuring those UITextFields in IB is extremely helpful, except that it seems to be the wrong approach.

Code snippit from tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath: below...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
int row = indexPath.row;

if (indexPath.section == kSectionReg) {
    NSString *reuseIdent = @"RegCell";
    cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdent];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:reuseIdent] autorelease];
    }
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


    if (row == [self rowIndexForRegEmail]) {
        [regEmailText removeFromSuperview];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:regEmailText];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Email";
    } else if (row == [self rowIndexForRegPassword]) {
        [regPasswordText removeFromSuperview];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:regPasswordText];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Password";
    ... etc...
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to create the textfields programatically in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: In part because they are easier to configure in IB. Each textfield is configured differently, so the code would be a mess. Plus, I'd also like to see if my existing implementation can work, so I don't have to redo it all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think this is your problem:

```
    [regEmailText removeFromSuperview];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:regEmailText];
```

Memory management is implicit in the view hierarchy: views own (retain) their subviews. When you remove a view from its superview, it gets released, and if nothing else is retaining it, it gets deallocated.

You're doing this every time the table view asks for a cell, not just when the cell is first created: on the first pass, the textfield is still referenced by something(1) when you call `removeFromSuperview`, so it's still around on the next line for you to add it to the cell. On subsequent calls, there's nothing else retaining the textfield; it gets deallocated when you remove it from the cell, so it's gone by the next line where you re-add it -- that's why it disappears.(2)

The most straightforward fix is to make sure the textfield doesn't go away -- stick it in a retaining/strong ivar or property (or just `retain` it before you `removeFromSuperview` and `release` after `addSubview:`, if you're not using ARC). Another option might be to use different reusable cell identifiers for each cell that has a unique text field.

More generally, you might want to consider Apple's [technique for static row content](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW20). Or even better: if you're on iOS 5, you can do a static table entirely in IB using a storyboard.

---

(1)(2): Exactly what references it at first, and why some of the fields get resized, is less straightforward and depends partly on stuff not shown in your question. I've gotta run right now -- the rest of my answer should solve your problem, and I'll edit this answer with details for further enlightenment later.

Comment: That link looks very interesting; thanks! I'll certainly peruse it and see what it can offer.

Regarding the memory management, the text views are actually @properties marked with "retain", so even when they aren't contained within a superview, they should still have a positive retain count. But it's a good point about the unnecessary removeFromSuperview call; I'd rather remove anything that's superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to totally fall apart. (Which i guess you've already told us it has)

I assume you are treating this as a "static table view" - i.e. the same number of cells with the same type of data will ever be there.

The problem is if any of the cells are scrolled out of view they will be reused, since they're all reuse identified as @"RegCell".

Aside: you *don't* need to removeFromSuperview, the reparenting will be fine when you add to subview.

You only want to build your view hierarchy once.  They look similar, but if they're different, use different reuse identifiers.  If they're the same, only build them the first time (inside the `if (cell == nil)`.

Comment: That's a good point. I did for awhile have each cell with its own reuse identifier and the same results occurred. However, you're probably right; if I'm ever going to get to a solution, the first thing would be to ensure that none of the cells get reused.

You are correct also that it's a "static table view"; ostensibly all rows are always visible at the same time, although scrolling can occur when the keyboard is visible.